# Place a “metadata” column on first page, next to title

Tags: positioning, margins, titles

I'd like to add a small column to my documents, which would then list additional article metadata like the editor or DOI. This is roughly what I mean:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[reversemp, includemp, marginparwidth=3.5cm]{geometry}
\title{Metadata in Margin}
\author{Bird}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\marginpar{
  \begin{flushleft}
  Document metadata goes here.
  \end{flushleft}
}

Nullam eu ante vel est convallis dignissim. Fusce suscipit, wisi
nec facilisis facilisis, est dui fermentum leo, quis tempor ligula
erat quis odio. Nunc porta vulputate tellus. Nunc rutrum turpis
sed pede. Sed bibendum. Aliquam posuere. Nunc aliquet, augue nec
adipiscing interdum, lacus tellus malesuada massa, quis varius mi
purus non odio.
\end{document}
```

[image: Minimal example of a metadata column]

However, the above causes issues if both the title and the metadata section are very long, in which case the column is moved to the second page.

I tried using `textpos`, like so:

```latex
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

% ⋮

\begin{textblock*}{3.5cm}(2cm,43.8mm) % place metadata at hard-coded location
  \begin{minipage}{3.5cm}
    Document metadata goes here.
  \end{minipage}
\end{textblock*}
```

But that's brittle and breaks (i.e., gets visually misplaced) whenever I update the page layout.

Is there a clean method that would allow me to place such a metadata column on the first page in a way that is robust to long titles and changes to the header or margins?

Comment: Note that things like this are a lot easier to control if you make your own title system instead of using  the standard `\maketitle`

Comment: @daleif thank you, that seems like a good suggestion. I'm fairly clueless when it comes to titles though. Do you have a resource that you would recommend in this context?